# Getting exceptions when I attempt to serialize GWT

Tags: gwt

When I serialize the one of my object I got serialization exception. The object I created satisfies all the requirements for a object to get serialize in gwt like implements IsSerializable and having a default constructor etc. I have attached a stack trace. Could any one help please.

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.check(SerializerBase.java:161)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.java:17)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.subex.rocforms.client.lib.FSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(FSModel_FieldSerializer.java:36)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:54)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:12)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.customcomponents.canvas.CanvasItemModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(CanvasItemModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.customcomponents.canvas.CellOverlayModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(CellOverlayModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:36)
    at com.subex.rocforms.client.lib.FSListModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(FSListModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.java:17)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.subex.rocforms.client.lib.FSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(FSModel_FieldSerializer.java:36)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:54)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:12)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.customcomponents.canvas.CanvasItemModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(CanvasItemModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.customcomponents.canvas.VertexModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(VertexModel_FieldSerializer.java:18)
    at com.subex.moneta.web.app.client.module.businesshierarchyconfig.BhNodeModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(BhNodeModel_FieldSerializer.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:36)
    at com.subex.rocforms.client.lib.FSListModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(FSListModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.java:17)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.subex.rocforms.client.lib.FSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(FSModel_FieldSerializer.java:36)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:54)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:12)
    at com.subex.moneta.web.app.client.module.businesshierarchyconfig.CanvasDfnModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(CanvasDfnModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(RpcMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModelData_FieldSerializer.java:17)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(BaseModel_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.subex.rocforms.client.lib.FSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(FSModel_FieldSerializer.java:36)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractBaseFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:54)
    at com.subex.spark.web.app.client.framework.models.AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(AbstractFSModel_FieldSerializer.java:12)
    at com.subex.moneta.web.app.client.module.businesshierarchyconfig.BusinessHierarchyModel_FieldSerializer.serialize(BusinessHierarchyModel_FieldSerializer.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase$MethodMap$.serialize$(SerializerBase.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.serialize(SerializerBase.java:147)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ClientSerializationStreamWriter.java:199)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
    at com.subex.moneta.web.app.client.module.businesshierarchyconfig.BusinessHierarchyConfigDetailService_Proxy.saveModel(BusinessHierarchyConfigDetailService_Proxy.java:208)
    at com.subex.moneta.web.app.client.module.businesshierarchyconfig.AbstractBusinessHierarchyConfigDetail$7.execute(AbstractBusinessHierarchyConfigDetail.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.CommandExecutor.doExecuteCommands(CommandExecutor.java:310)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.CommandExecutor$2.run(CommandExecutor.java:205)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer.fire(Timer.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor420.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessages(BrowserChannel.java:1668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the stack trace, it is hard to tell what the cause is. A common problem with serialization is that all non-static, non-transient fields need to be serializable as well - this might be worth checking.